# How to plot Leminscate shape using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

How to plot this Leminscate `(−π/4 =< φ =< π/4)`?

```
x = cos(φ)sqrt(2cos(2φ))
y = sin(φ)sqrt(2cos(2φ))
```

This is my attempt:

```
x = -pi/4:0.001:pi/4;
xy = cos(x).*sqrt(2*cos(2.*x));
yy = sin(x).*sqrt(2*cos(2.*x));
plot(x,xy,x,yy)
axis equal
grid on
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Show us your actual code, not text equations. Also, be more explicit with what you mean by "it didn't work".

Answer (score 0):

Following code segment may help you to find the solution. Next time, please clearly mention what you have tried and any error messages you saw.

```
x = -pi/4:pi/256:pi/4;

yx = cos(x).*sqrt(2*cos(2.*x));
yy = sin(x).*sqrt(2*cos(2.*x));

plot(x,yx,x,yy);
```

Comment: The OP clearly wants a parametric plot so use `plot(yx,yy)` would be more appropriate. However, this still only plots half of the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
theta = linspace (-pi/4,pi/4);
x = cos(theta).*sqrt(2.*cos(2.*theta));
y = sin(theta).*sqrt(2.*cos(2.*theta));
plot(x,y,-x,-y), grid on, 
axis ('equal')
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsUm4.png)